# Is this String.Compare CodeRush suggestion one that I should take?

Tags: vb.net

Dim rowChinaVisa As DataRow

CodeRush is suggesting that I change this line

```
If rowChinaVisa("sex").ToString = "M" Then
```

to:

```
If String.Compare(rowChinaVisa("sex").ToString, "M", False) = 0 Then
```

I prefer how the orig line reads, but I am wondering if the recommended line is more efficient. Perhaps for LONG strings only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is more readable, but String.Compare has better performance, but for such a small string it doesnt really matter.

I tried to find an article I read a while back where the guy compared performance on different string compare and equals methods, if anyone knows what im talking about please link me :p

Comment: That was my suspicion. Still, I would be interested in an answer to your question. ty

Comment: Take look at String.CompareOrdinal, this has good performance and is faster than String.Compare.

Comment: Also keep in mind that string.compare (and it's related functions) can take into account regional comparison issues, that a simple = compare won't

Comment: The equality operator (=) calls the String.Equals method. You can read about performance of these methods (Equals and Compare) here: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2010/09/22/what-s-faster-string-equals-or-string-compare.aspx